# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//http://localhost:8080/hibernate_test

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I use Hibernate 3. I get `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//http://localhost:8080/hibernate_test` exception in logs.

See all logs:

```
[main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.4.Final
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : com/mapping/user.hbm.xml
[main] WARN org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: com.entity.user -> user_table
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql//http://localhost:8080/hibernate_test
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
[main] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//http://localhost:8080/hibernate_test
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
    at main.main(main.java:16)
[main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
[main] INFO org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader - Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
[main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
[main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
[main] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Echoing all SQL to stdout
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
[main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
[main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayClobType@7cf42466
[main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveCharacterArrayClobType@81e4a1
[main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@4fc90649
[main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType@16bbcb8b
[main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@3301e56
[main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@3301e56
[main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@4c17a1bc
[main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@4c17a1bc
[main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType@237b64ab
[main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
[main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
[main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//http://localhost:8080/hibernate_test
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at main.main(main.java:19)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//http://localhost:8080/hibernate_test
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 5 more
```

My **main.java** class is:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.entity.user;


public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     user user =new user();
     user.setUsername("ali");
     user.setPassword("123456");

   SessionFactory sessionfactory=  new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

   Session session =sessionfactory.openSession();
   session.beginTransaction();
   session.save(user);
   session.getTransaction().commit();
   session.close();



    }

}
```

My Xml file **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql//http://localhost:8080/hibernate_test</property> 
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
           <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

            <!-- Configuration hibernate -->
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="format_sql">true</property>  
            <property name="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</property>
        <mapping resource="com/mapping/user.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What is throwing this exception? How to fix it?

Comment: `jdbc:mysql//http://localhost:8080/` That is not a valid database URL. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/. Also, the current stable version of Hibernate is 5.1. Why are your learning with Hibernate 3, which is not supported anymore, and obsolete?

Comment: question description, code format

Comment: Well the root problem reside in the question title itself

Comment: by following your advice, I see that the application was created. but I still have this problem.

Comment: [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        user_table
        (username, password) 
    values
        (?, ?)
[main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
[main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Base table or view not found message from server: "Table 'hibernate_test.user_table' doesn't exist"
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.entity.user]

Comment: thx for @JB Nizet, takeit, Alexandre Lavoie, Lucas Crawford

Answer (score 1):

Make URL be:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/hibernate_test
```

Read the article here for URL's with JDBC:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

> jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]] »
>   [?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]

Directly taken from that link